# How to replace ". " with ".\n" with standard utilities?

Tags: unix, sed, posix

How can I replace all sequences of a dot followed by a space with a dot followed by a new line?
On a unix box, with POSIX tools.

I thought `sed` or `tr` might be up for the job. But I can not figure it out.
I tried things like

```sh
sed 's/. /.\n/g' file
```

Reading
[How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) did not make it happen for me.

EDIT: I was lost between the different escapes and forgot that I should escape the dot. so `sed 's/\. /\.\n/g' file` works for me.

Comment: `.` matches (almost) any character. Escape it: `sed 's/\. /.\n/g' file`

Comment: @Biffen thanks! Great concise answer. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all `sed` will treat `\n` as a newline character in the replacement string.  But you can escape the newline.
eg:

```
$ echo foo. bar | sed 's/\. /.\
> /'
foo.
bar
```

or

```
$ n='                               
'
$ echo foo. bar | sed "s/\. /.\\$n/"
foo.
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you could easily do it by using its `gsub` function. This should work in any version of `awk` IMHO. You could simply globally substitute literal DOT followed by space with dot and ORS(which is new line) and then simply print the line.

```
awk '{gsub(/\. /,"."ORS)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner, where `[.]` is a character class that consists only of a period:

```
perl -pe 's{[.] }{.\n}g' in_file
```

To change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{[.] }{.\n}g' in_file
```